# Angular injection error on input directives after minification

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Every thing works fine in my angular app. But when I minify the app every page that contains **input** directive raises injection error.

> Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.4/$injector/unpr?p0=nProvider%20%3C-%20n%20%3C-%20inputDirective

**Update**
This is how I inject dependencies:

```
var reportServiceId = 'TheReportService';
      ReportController.$inject = ['$scope', 'common', reportServiceId, 'reportState', '$timeout', '$location', '$stateParams', 'dateTimeService'];
        function ReportController($scope, common, reportService, reportState, $timeout, location, $stateParams, dateTimeService) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.title = "Transaction Log";
            var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
            var log = getLogFn(reportControllerId);

            vm.getRanges = reportService.getRanges();
            vm.criteria = getParams();
            ...
```

Comment: what is your code before you try to minify it? Have you read their note about [minification](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification)?

Comment: @PatrickEvans: Yes, minification works fine for whole app until I add a very simple input tag to a html template

Comment: Some of your code would still be useful.

Comment: updated my Q with injection part of the code

Comment: `"reportServiceId"` needs to be a string in `.$inject = [.., reportServiceId, ..]`, and you are missing the actual injectible parameter in the controller for this data

Comment: @New Dev: Thanks, but reportServiceId is assigned properly and every thing works perfectly even after minification unless I add a very simple "input" directive.